# Forward FTP to another Server

Tags: server, proxy, iptables, firewall, ftp

I am trying to forward all incoming FTP Connections at Server A to another Server B. I tried this using iptables and am able to connect in first step. The problem is that after entering the passive mode and sending the MLSD command i am getting a `GnuTLS-Error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated` and my connection gets aborted. I need to use passive ftp.

Server A (Proxy):

- IP is 192.168.178.20
- IPv4 forwarding is active
- nf_nat_ftp is active
- nf_conntrack_ftp is active

iptables:

```
# general rules for forwarding traffic between external interface tap0 and internal interface eth0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tap0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i tap0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tap0 -j ACCEPT

# NAT for active/passive FTP. 192.168.178.21 would be your internal ftp server
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp  --dport 20 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.21:20
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp  --dport 21 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.21:21
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp  --dport 1024:65535 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.21:1024-65535
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.178.21 -p tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.178.21 -p tcp --sport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.178.21 -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT

# allowing active/passive FTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT
```

(German) Connection Log from FileZilla to proxy:

```
Status:         Verbindung hergestellt, warte auf Willkommensnachricht...
Status:         Initialisiere TLS...
Status:         Überprüfe Zertifikat...
Status:         TLS-Verbindung hergestellt.
Status:         Angemeldet
Status:         Empfange Verzeichnisinhalt...
Befehl:         PWD
Antwort:        257 "/" is your current location
Befehl:         TYPE I
Antwort:        200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Befehl:         PASV
Antwort:        227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,178,21,156,206)
Befehl:         MLSD
Fehler:         GnuTLS-Fehler -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status:         Server hat die TLS-Verbindung nicht ordnungsgemäß geschlossen
Fehler:         Übertragungsverbindung unterbrochen: ECONNABORTED - Verbindung abgebrochen
Fehler:         Anzeigen des Verzeichnisinhalts durch Benutzer abgebrochen
```

Server B (FTP Server):

- using pure-ftpd
- IP is 192.168.178.21
- FTP Server uses ports 40110-40210

Syslog from FTP Server when the connection through the proxy arrives:

```
Jun 30 20:06:02 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (?@192.168.178.20) [INFO] New connection from 192.168.178.20
Jun 30 20:06:02 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (?@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [auth] [TLS]
Jun 30 20:06:02 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (?@192.168.178.20) [INFO] SSL/TLS: Enabled TLSv1/SSLv3 with AES256-GCM-SHA384, 256 secret bits cipher
Jun 30 20:06:03 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (?@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [user] [ftpuser_1]
Jun 30 20:06:03 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (?@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [pass] []
Jun 30 20:06:03 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (?@192.168.178.20) [INFO] ftpuser_1 is now logged in
Jun 30 20:06:03 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (ftpuser_1@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [opts] [UTF8 ON]
Jun 30 20:06:03 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (ftpuser_1@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [pbsz] [0]
Jun 30 20:06:03 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (ftpuser_1@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [prot] [P]
Jun 30 20:06:03 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (ftpuser_1@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [pwd] []
Jun 30 20:06:04 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (ftpuser_1@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [type] [I]
Jun 30 20:06:04 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (ftpuser_1@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [pasv] []
Jun 30 20:06:04 ftpserver pure-ftpd: (ftpuser_1@192.168.178.20) [DEBUG] Command [mlsd] []
```

I am able to connect to the ftp server directly, so I was wondering if I have to think about the tls.